# failing to transfer a file through a socket, java

Tags: java, sockets

here's a little code. This class runs on two computers, one side sends a file (send()) and the other one recieves it (read()). I know send() works because when i run school solution (its an assignment) it can download a file from me, but for some reason when i try to download the file is created (by the constructor) but read doesn't write anything into the file.

```
public class SendFile extends BasicMessage implements Message{

private File _file;

public SendFile(CommandEnum caption){
    super(caption);
}

public SendFile(String file){
    super(CommandEnum.FILE);
    _file = new File(FMDataManager.instance().getSharedDirectory(),file);
}

public void send (DataOutputStream out) throws IOException{
    out.writeUTF(_caption.toString());
    out.writeLong(_file.length());
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(_file);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    for (int i=0; i<_file.length(); i++)
        out.write(bis.read());
    out.writeUTF(CommandEnum.END.toString());
}

public void read(DataInputStream in) throws IOException{
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(_file);
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    in.readUTF();
    long size = in.readLong();
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        bos.write(in.read());
    System.out.println(in.readUTF());
}

}
```

any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must close your streams to ensure it is correct.  In your particular case, file content is probably still inside the BufferedOutputStream.

Comment: as you can see i get data streams as an arguments in those method. this stream is later close in the same class it was created, do you still think it could be the problem?